# U-SQL How to select top 3 exceptions for each date

Tags: sql, azure, u-sql

How can i extract the top 3 exceptions per day with U-SQL?

[image]

I want the result to look like this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use group by and sum and things like that.. That should get you going

Comment: I solved it with ARRAY_AGG  on Exception with grouping on Date. Then i got an array for each date. From here i could use some inline C# to return the first three indexes in the array! :)

Comment: Classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.

Answer (score 4):

One way to accomplish this in U-SQL is to use the `ROW_NUMBER` ranking function partitioned by date and ordered by your count descending.  For example:

```
@input = SELECT *
     FROM (
        VALUES
            ( "2016-01-01T00:00:00", "System.ArgumentNullException", 7 ),
            ( "2016-01-01T00:00:00", "System.IO.EndOfStreamException", 5 ),
            ( "2016-01-01T00:00:00", "System.IO.FileNotFoundException", 4 ),
            ( "2016-01-01T00:00:00", "System.IndexOutofRangeException", 4 ),
            ( "2016-01-01T00:00:00", "System.ArgumentException", 3 ),
            ( "2016-01-02T00:00:00", "System.BadImageFormatException", 18 ),
            ( "2016-01-02T00:00:00", "System.IO.EndOfStreamException", 16 ),
            ( "2016-01-02T00:00:00", "System.NotImplementedException", 14 ),
            ( "2016-01-02T00:00:00", "System.UnauthorizedAccessException", 13 ),
            ( "2016-01-02T00:00:00", "System.ArgumentException", 12 ),
            ( "2016-01-02T00:00:00", "System.IndexOutofRangeException", 5 ),
            ( "2016-01-03T00:00:00", "System.IO.EndOfStreamException", 45 ),
            ( "2016-01-03T00:00:00", "System.FormatException", 42 ),
            ( "2016-01-03T00:00:00", "System.BadImageFormatException", 41 ),
            ( "2016-01-03T00:00:00", "System.IndexOutofRangeException", 41 ),
            ( "2016-01-03T00:00:00", "System.IO.FileNotFoundException", 40 )

     ) AS x(date, exception, count);



// Add row number to resultset based on date and count descending
@working =
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY count DESC) AS rn,
           *
    FROM @input;


// Top 3 by date?
@output =
    SELECT *
    FROM @working
    WHERE rn <= 3;


OUTPUT @output TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

My results:

[image: Results]